# Create Emails from Excel Loop

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have this sample sheet:
[image: SheetSample]

My code currently goes through and creates emails based on the name in column H.  So Approver1 gets one email for all his people.  I have gotten it to de-dupe any repeats of their employee names.  Example:  Approver 1 gets an email that says 'please approve time for all of your employees below:' and then there is a list of names...Sample1, Sample2, and Sample3.  The sheet will often have dupe employees for each approver, as shown in my sheet above.

The code works well for the first set of dupe names (there could be up to 10 of the same Approvers in a row, all getting one email), then runs fine through any singles.

When it hits the next set of repeated approvers it skips the first row in that group, then creates emails for every **other** division; so it skips a row until it gets to the end of the dupe approver section.  So from the sheet, approver1 would get his email all set, then approver2 would get hers, but then approver3 becomes a mess.

How do I get this to loop correctly through an entire list, creating one email for each approver, with all the corresponding names of their people listed only once?

```
Sub DivisionApprovals()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell, lookrng As Range
    Dim strdir As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strName As Variant
    Dim strName1 As Variant
    Dim strDept As Variant
    Dim strName2 As String
    Dim strbody2 As String
    Dim strName3 As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    r = 2

    Do While r <= rng.rows.count
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        Set strName = rng.Cells(r, 1)
        Set strName3 = rng.Cells(r, 3)
        strName2 = Trim(Split(strName, ",")(1))

        strBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strName2 & ", <br><br> Please approve the following divisions:<br><br>"

        With OutMail
            .To = rng.Cells(r, 2).Value
            .Subject = "Please Approve Divisions"
            List = strName3 & "<br>"


            Do While rng.Cells(r, 1).Value = rng.Cells(r + 1, 1)
                r = r + 1
                Set strDept = rng.Cells(r, 3)
                .Subject = "Approvals Needed!"
                List = .HTMLBody & strDept & "<br>"
                r = r + 1
                .HTMLBody = List
            Loop
            .HTMLBody = strBody & "<B>" & List & "</B>" & "<br>" & Signature
            .Display

        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend, you first go through that column and make a list of unique names.  Then you have something to check against.  If you walk through that list, each unique person will get get a unique email.  You could insert a unique column beside your list of names.

Comment: What is Division- a msg that needs to go in the email body?

Comment: Division can go in the body, yes.  So email would read, 'Sample1, please approve Widgets and Doorknobs' then a new email for Sample2 to approve brooms.  Then, if Sample3 had 2 or more divisions, it would loop and add of those divisions attached to Sample3, and so on.

Comment: Looking at the code, I believe the intention is that the names column is sorted before the email and dept portion begins. The give away is the do while with the row increment on checking.  Sooo . . . .let's add a sort to this and it might work as you want.

Comment: Alright @learningthisstuff I figured out what was going on, the code assumes the names are sorted.  One thing not provided for is if the dept names are the same it will be listed multiple times, are the dept always unique for a person (no dupes?) if there are dupes that is different code.

Comment: The list is already sorted by name.  The names are approvers.  The divisions need to be added to the body of the email so that if one person has 4 divisions, they will get an email with only their division names.  My code does that okay to start but when it hits a section with multiple divisions going to the same person, it is skipping the first division in that section, so if there were 4 divisions going to sample3, it would skip the entire first line.  So sample3 would only get 3 divisions, not 4.

Comment: posted code below, I did not test your code as written because there was no guarantee of a sort and the code won't work "properly" without it.  So I provided the sort.  I tried to name the boundaries so you will know what they are and can change if things change. There are a few things added to the code but the sort prior to processing is the major factor.  The lastRow usage is another one, you will always use this, keep it handy.  Other than that it is the exact same mechanism as you posted.

Comment: Hi Wookie, thanks, I will look but please see my edit to my original question, as I noted, the request to me changed, so now I have posted a revised sheet.  Same idea overall, but hopefully it better conveys what I need to do and why I am having this issue (which is why the pivot and your original code stub helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the previous answer, then un-deleted it in case you need that info.  So as to not confuse anyone, the answer building from the OP's code is below.

DISCLAIMER: I am not a fan of the incrementing code style in the Do While, it make sit very difficult to chase errors but I understand the intention.  I have included code below this in the way that my brain works and perhaps better coding style, you be the judge.

Alright @learningthisstuff I figured out what was going on, the code assumes the names are sorted.  One thing not provided for is if the dept names are the same it will be listed multiple times, are the dept always unique for a person (no dupes?) if there are dupes that is different code.

This code works I just ran it as a macro on a dummy set.  Big thing was the sort AND the incrementing logic, I changed a few things to make it more readable/understandable along the way.

I hope this helps you and you can modify as things change for you.

```
Sub Email_Macro()
'
' Email_Macro Macro
'
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell, lookrng As Range
    Dim strdir As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strName As Variant
    Dim strName1 As Variant
    Dim strDept As Variant
    Dim strName2 As String
    Dim strbody2 As String
    Dim strName3 As Variant
    Dim emailWS As Worksheet
    Dim nameCol As Double
    Dim deptCol As Double
    Dim lastRow As Double
    Dim startRow As Double
    Dim r As Double

    Dim depList As String
    deptList = ""


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    Set emailWS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    startRow = 2 ' starting row
    nameCol = 1 'col of name
    deptCol = 3 'col of dept

    'find the last row with a name in it from the name column
    lastRow = emailWS.Cells(emailWS.Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'set variable to the starting row #
    r = startRow 'this is where the counting begins

    'sort the data first before going through the email process
    'assumes these are the only columns 1 (nameCol) thru 3 (deptCol) to sort
    'assumes you are sorting based on col 1 (nameCol)
    emailWS.Range(Cells(startRow, nameCol), Cells(lastRow, deptCol)).Sort key1:=emailWS.Range(Cells(startRow, nameCol), Cells(lastRow, nameCol))

    Do While r <= lastRow
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        Set strName = emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol)
        Set strName3 = emailWS.Cells(r, deptCol)
        'careful the line below assumes there is always a comma separator in the name
        strName2 = Trim(Split(strName, ",")(1))

        strBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strName2 & ", <br><br> Please approve the following divisions:<br><br>"

        With OutMail
            .To = emailWS.Cells(r, 2).Value
            .Subject = "Please Approve Divisions"
            deptList = strName3 & "<br>"


            Do While emailWS.Cells(r, 1).Value = emailWS.Cells(r + 1, 1)
                r = r + 1
                Set strDept = emailWS.Cells(r, 3)
                .Subject = "Approvals Needed!"
                deptList = deptList & strDept & "<br>"
            Loop
            .HTMLBody = strBody & "<B>" & deptList & "</B>" & "<br>" & Signature
            .Display

        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing

        'conditionally increment the row based on the name difference
        If emailWS.Cells(r, 1).Value <> emailWS.Cells(r + 1, 1) Then
            r = r + 1 'increment if there is a new name or no name
            deptList = "" 'reset the department list
        Else 'Do nothing
        End If
    Loop
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

To prove that I don't throw out comments without backing it up with some solution / mentoring?  This is much easier for me to understand and troubleshoot. It steps through the rows in a very predictable fashion and we handle each row based on specified conditions.  I also try and use variable names that will let you know what they are for.

```
Sub Email_Macro()
'
' Email_Macro Macro
'
    Dim OutApp As Object 'email application
    Dim OutMail As Object 'email object
    Dim strBody As String 'first line of email body
    Dim strName As String 'name in the cell we are processing
    Dim strDept As String 'dept of the name we are processing
    Dim previousName As String 'previous name processed
    Dim nextName As String 'next name to process

    Dim emailWS As Worksheet 'the worksheet selected wehn running macro
    Dim nameCol As Double 'column # of names
    Dim deptCol As Double 'column # of depts
    Dim lastRow As Double 'last row of data in column
    Dim startRow As Double 'row we wish to start processing on
    Dim r As Double 'loop variable for row
    'This will be the list of departments, we will build it as we go
    Dim depList As String
    Dim strSig As String 'email signature
    strSig = "Respectfully, <br> Wookie"

    deptList = "" 'empty intitialization
    previousName = "" 'empty intialization
    nextName = "" 'empty intialization

    'Turn off screen updating
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'choose email application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'set worksheet to work on as active (selected sheet)
    Set emailWS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    startRow = 2 ' starting row
    nameCol = 1 'col of names, can also do nameCol = emailWS.Range("A1").Column
    deptCol = 3 'col of depts, can also do deptCol = emailWS.Range("A3").Column
    '** Advantage of the optional way is if you have many columns and you don't want to count them

    'find the last row with a name in it from the name column
    lastRow = emailWS.Cells(emailWS.Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'sort the data first before going through the email process using Range sort and a key
    'assumes these are the only columns 1 (nameCol) thru 3 (deptCol) to sort
    'assumes you are sorting based on col 1 (nameCol)
    emailWS.Range(Cells(startRow, nameCol), Cells(lastRow, deptCol)).Sort key1:=emailWS.Range(Cells(startRow, nameCol), Cells(lastRow, nameCol))

    'Set up our loop, it will go through every cell in the column we select in the loop
    For r = startRow To lastRow
        'Get the name and dept
        'For the name we will split around the comma and take the second part of array (right of comma)
        strName = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol), ",")(1))
        strDept = emailWS.Cells(r, deptCol)

        'if the next name is not blank (EOF)
        If emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol) <> "" Then
           'assign the next name
           nextName = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol), ",")(1))
        Else
           'this is your EOF exit so assume a name
           nextName = "Exit"
        End If 'Else do noting on this If

        If strName <> previousName Then
            'Set our "new" name to previousName for looping
            'process the "new" name
            previousName = strName
            'create the email object
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            'Process as new email
            With OutMail
                .To = strName 'address email to the name
                .Subject = "Please Approve Divisions" 'appropriate subject
                deptList = strDept & "<br>" 'add the dept to dept list
                'Build the first line of email body in HTML format
                strBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strName & ", <br><br> Please approve the following divisions:<br><br>"
            End With
        Else
            'The name is the same as the email we opened
            'Process Dept only by adding it to string with a line break
            deptList = deptList & strDept & "<br>"
        End If

        'Do we send the email and get ready for another?
        If strName <> nextName Then
            'the next name is not the same as the one we are processing and we sorted first
            'so it is time to send the email
            OutMail.HTMLBody = strBody & "<B>" & deptList & "</B>" & "<br><br>" & strSig
            OutMail.Display

        Else 'Do Nohing
        End If

Next r 'move to the next row

'nullify email reference
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

If you want to guard against duplicate departments then I would do it like this, you can see where this goes there is only one end with:

```
    End With
Else
    'The name is the same as the email we opened
    'Process Dept only by adding it to string with a line break
    If InStr(deptList, strDept) = 0 Then
        'Dept is not in the list so Add the department
        deptList = deptList & strDept & "<br>"
    Else
        'Do nothing, the dept is already there
    End If
End If
```

I suppose never give up.  Everything is possible, maybe just outside of our current skillset (so get some help and keep learning).

Cheers - WWC

Comment: I now the names are not in the right format in the dummy set.  I was in a hurry, the dummy set also began in randomized order, it gets sorted along the way.

Comment: one more thing.  Just a matter of observation, this code uses 2 subject lines, anyone with duplicate departments gets 1 version ("Approvals Needed!") and anyone in the list only once gets another version ("Please Approve Divisions")

Comment: Wow Wookie, this came really close!  I got it to run, but in mine, it skipped an approver name (so no email), grouping a set of two approvers together on one email to one the first approver.  Then, in the next approver with multiple divisions/employees, it skipped the first  and last names for an approver.  I am going through line by line via F8, but not seeing what the issue is.  It could be because as I noted, it changed (I adapted your code to work with my revised sheet) and the fact that there are dupe employees/divisions too?

Comment: Also, if you look at your screenshot, you will see your code is having the same issue I am....look at jill.  she is missing coconuts but has mini guns, steering links, brooms.  Bill is missing pears and ugly pears.  See what I mean?

Comment: You were right, it was the incrementing of r near the bottom of the loop, it needs to be conditional, if it is always done then it skips the last instance of the name.  Give this a try.  Very specific to what you started with and your format, I would suggest another way, as this way can be tricky.

Comment: thanks, i might go the pivot route if I can figure out how to pull the field ranges (been reading up on it) BUT for now, your adjusted code is almost there!  It is now creating the email sets correctly BUT it is populating all of the names in the list, including dupes.  So from my sheet above, it creates a single email to the approver but has Sample1 twice, and Sample2 3 times.  I want to list them once each.  I am trying to work that out now.  How did you get that string to run as a list (deptlist)?  I thought you could only do that with dictionaries!

Comment: Wookie, I just had a revelation...why don't I just filter out all the dupes, then run the code we have??  Can it be that I am that dumb??  Going to try it by adding the VBA to remove dupes.

Comment: Dupes of names or dupes of departments.  Now that depts is a string we can search for a match with instr function to see if the dept is already there, if so, don't add it.  New code above, I like it better.

Comment: Departments/Employees.  So the approvers (names) can be duped.  It is the depts/employees piece that needs to be de-duped.  I will look at your new code but I did get it to work late last night by adding a de-dupe line to the code.

Comment: Okay Wookie, you are a true champion!!  Your version worked better for de-duping than mine did.  I made some modifications on my end to adapt to my new, larger sheet (things like rows, columns, sort, etc) and it ran perfectly!!  WOOT and WOOHOO!  This is something I have been working on for months.  The key to this was your piece at the end, the conditionals.  Those are what fixed the issue of the loops skipping rows, and then your next loop for de-duping the lists.  You have no idea how grateful I am.  I wish I could buy you a beer, or give you more rep than just selecting your answer!

Comment: Just enjoy the win, and help out others that get as stuck as you and I do!  It takes a community, glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little helper stub I use to find a unique list from column A and place that list in column C.  Based on a button click.  Modify as you wish.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim thisWS As Worksheet
 Dim firstRow As Double
 Dim lastRow As Double
 Dim workCol As Double
 Dim dataRange As Range
 Dim uniqueLast As Double
 Dim uniqueCol As Double
 Dim i As Double
 Dim y As Double
 Dim Temp As String
 Dim found_Bool As Boolean

 Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 workCol = thisWS.Range("A1").Column
 firstRow = 1
 uniqueLast = 1
 uniqueCol = thisWS.Range("C1").Column
 lastRow = thisWS.Cells(thisWS.Rows.Count, workCol).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = firstRow To lastRow
    Temp = Trim(UCase(thisWS.Range(Cells(i, workCol), Cells(i, workCol))))
    Temp = Replace(Temp, "#", "")
    found_Bool = False
    For y = 1 To uniqueLast
        If Temp = thisWS.Range(Cells(y, uniqueCol), Cells(y, uniqueCol)) Then
          found_Bool = True
        Else ' Do nothing
        End If


    Next y

    If found_Bool = False Then
          thisWS.Range(Cells(uniqueLast + 1, uniqueCol), Cells(uniqueLast + 1, uniqueCol)) = Temp
          uniqueLast = uniqueLast + 1
    Else
    End If

 Next i
End Sub
```

Once you do this you can lookup each name in the non unique column and get the appropriate dept for subject or other info.

What you want is really a pivot in VBA (name & dept(s), you could just vba the pivot, that is a little trickier but very doable.

```
'***************************************************
```

OK take what Scott has and its very workable.  With regard to the pivot table itself a few "helpers". Again, either name the table and just update the range or delete it and make it each time.  Do to the project I delete it every time here and keep using the same space to make picot after picot, every time the workbook is opened this scratch space is clear.

This is me creating a pivot of sales data, bear with me, I actually copy the pivot data afterwards to values and then add columns to perform calculations, then I move that to a report, deleting the pivot and working table, basically this all happens away from what the user gets to see when they click a button:

```
   '***************************
    'Add Sales Pivot Table
   'Last DR is the last data row, you can see it done several times, in the code below, once you do it you will always do it
   'CalcSheet is the name of the worksheet in the workbook I am working on
   'The range here is defined in Range Format, you could use a named range or use .Range(Cells(row,col),Cells(row,col)) there are several ways
   'I name the pivot table upon creation so I can manipulate it better
   'I specify the target cell, upper left with which to begin the pivot table

   ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        CalcSheet.Range("K14:AY" & LastDR), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=CalcSheet.Range("CA37"), TableName:="SalesPVT", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

I set the pivot up in the format that I want and then I sort it based on one of the fields:

```
With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Salesperson")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Customer")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("DD Rev")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
End With

With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Job Days")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With

CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Salesperson").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of DD Rev"
```

Perhaps there is another way but now I do not know the dimensions of the pivot table (rows) do I? So I define them here based on the first column where I placed the pivot table and the anchor range I specified in creation:

```
'Find the last row of Pivot table Data

Dim LastPVTrow As Double
Dim FirstPVTrow As Double
Dim NumPVTrows As Double
Dim PivCol As Double

PivCol = CalcSheet.Range("CB37").Column

FirstPVTrow = CalcSheet.Range("CB37").Row
LastPVTrow = CalcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, PivCol).End(xlUp).Row
NumPVTrows = LastPVTrow - FirstPVTrow
```

Here I make a column somewhere else based on the pivot data, your email could occur about right here if you wanted:
'make the Avg Rev/Job Day Column

```
    For i = 1 To NumPVTrows ' four columns in this table
        CalcSheet.Range("CD" & (100 + i)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        If CalcSheet.Range("CC" & (FirstPVTrow + i)) <> 0 Then
            CalcSheet.Range("CD" & (100 + i)) = CalcSheet.Range("CB" & (FirstPVTrow + i)) / CalcSheet.Range("CC" & (FirstPVTrow + i))
        Else
            CalcSheet.Range("CD" & (100 + i)) = 0
        End If
   Next i
```

'Here I am going to leave a bunch of stuff out but it puts headers on my table that is only missing the pivot and adds some more columns and calculations, counts the values based on specified ranges etc and finds averages

'Then I copy the pivot table and delete it, happens every time a button is clicked and a new workbook is selected to process

```
'copy pivot table to get rid of it
 CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").TableRange1.Copy
'Paste it as values with formatting
CalcSheet.Range("CA100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Delete Sales Pivot from the file
 CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").TableRange1.Delete

'Clear Work Space
CalcSheet.Range("CA1:CN500").Clear
```

Once I have processed the sales persons, I do it again by customer in the same working scratch space, build a table make new columns and headers down below based on the data, copy the table as values and then after putting it into a report, delete it all, for the next go around.  I format my little table before export: bolding the headers, putting grey on the sales person or the customer, the totals line is blue, I right align the numbers in the cell, there sis  alot of code left out to focus on the pivot.

So here is similar pivot code building the table for customers

```
'***************************************
'Make the Customer Pivot and table
'***************************************

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        CalcSheet.Range("K14:AY" & LastDR), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=CalcSheet.Range("CA37"), TableName:="CustPVT", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("CustPVT").PivotFields("Customer")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("CustPVT").PivotFields("DD Rev")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    End With

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("CustPVT").PivotFields("Job Days")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With

'Find the last row of Pivot table Data

FirstPVTrow = CalcSheet.Range("CA37").Row
LastPVTrow = CalcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, PivCol).End(xlUp).Row
'LastPVTrow = CalcSheet.Range("CB37:CB500").Find((0), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
NumPVTrows = LastPVTrow - FirstPVTrow
```

etc. etc. etc . . .

I am sure the users on here are a lot more elegant.
I strive for code that is readable and usually understandable by me (hopefully others) and limited by my skillset, you have to come back to this stuff months or years later, trust me it looks different than when you are "living in the moment of creation"  Take the time to leave yourself bread crumbs, name your variables and your tables so they make sense.  Try an use named ranges rather than "hard coding" ranges, I know I did it here, do as I say . . . not as I do.  I will usually only do this in areas that will later be erased and wiped.  No excuses but I was moving in a rush on this one.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, the code got stuck on this:  Temp = Trim(UCase(thisWS.Range(Cells(i, workCol), Cells(i, workCol)))).  Says Method 'Range' of object_worksheet' failed.  How would I do the pivot in vba?  I would like to try that but have never done it in vba.

Comment: This is code that I use regularly, that is a strange error.  Did you change thisWS to be your worksheet?  You could always use Thisworkbook.Activesheet in the assignment if you are working with only one sheet.  I will dig up some pivot vba, but you can record macro and pivot and use Stack Overflow, to fill in the gaps as well.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the sheet name, but it still will not work, but thank  you anyway.  It appears that I will just never get this to work.  I am surprised that there is no way to do this.  I just need to loop through and group the dupes together, but it seems this is impossible in excel!

Comment: I don't think its impossible, perhaps chart out what you want to happen in the planning phase, grouping names and departments so you can send one email for each name on the list and then include the departments.  Excel is capable.  Part by part, the first is getting the data in from the database correctly.  Then working with that data pre email, then emailing.  This is very doable, but trying to help on SO is always like looking at only a piece of a project not the entire project.  Perhaps post your code to Github and link it here so we can pull it down and look at it.

Comment: sorry GitHub is where you can create a free account and post code (any language), if you share the repository others can pull down your code (fork it) and suggest the updates.  It is one way that version control and open source as well as multi-contributor lives in the code world.  Just a suggestion but this is how your helpers can get at your code.

Comment: Wow Wookie that is some crazy stuff!  Here I am, stuck back on what your original helper stub!  I wanted to comment and let you know that I actually got your code to work and have been able get the unique names, woot!  Now, I think I could use those and set the names to each approver, but am not sure how.  I was going to try offsets, but your code lists them all in succession.  Is there a way to keep their relative locations?  Meaning, it would have blank cells in between each new section based on the next unique approver (just like the pivot does).  Thanks!  At least I did SOMETHING!

Comment: yes, you can plan for blank cells.  Finding the last row of data in a column regardless of blanks then you can account for the blanks and get the dept as you step through the list.  Depending on the size of your data you can skirt the pivot table and do it "with brute force" if you prefer.  I might be able to shoe you an example of each way, just projects already written are very custom . .  without knowing the project of the example code some aspects can seem strange.

Comment: Wookie, is there a way to chat directly?  I want to explain to you exactly what I am doing, and show you my actual sheet, not the sample one I created for the post.  The issue is that my sheet has sort of evolved in the last week, so what I am trying to get done has changed slightly.

Answer (score 1):

If you pivot your data, here is a way to loop through the pivot to get unique information by name.

**Pivotted Data**

[image]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopPivot()

With Sheet1

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = .PivotTables(1)

    Dim nameField As PivotField
    Set nameField = pt.PivotFields("Name")

    Dim nameItem As PivotItem

    For Each nameItem In nameField.PivotItems

        Dim name As String
        name = nameItem.Value

        Dim emailField As PivotField
        Set emailField = pt.PivotFields("email")

        Dim emailItem As PivotItem
        Set emailItem = emailField.PivotItems(nameItem.Position)

        Dim email As String
        email = emailItem.Value

        Dim divisionName As Range

        Dim division As String
        division = vbNullString

        For Each divisionName In nameItem.DataRange

            division = division & "," & divisionName.Value

        Next

        division = Mid(division, 2, 255)

        Debug.Print name
        Debug.Print email
        Debug.Print division


    Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks, I tried to do this, but could not...do I have to create the pivot first?  I am looking for a solution that will do all the actions in vba, so I can distribute to users so they do not have to do anything but push a button.  Is there a way to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You have to create the pivot table. You can create it in VBA first if you need to. Record a macro of you doing it manually to get a start on the syntax. You'll need to tweak it after recording, but it will be a great start.

Comment: Scott, how did you get the data to look like that in your pivot table?  I have not been able to get it so show the Name, Email, and Division in that arrangement.

Comment: you could call the looppivot inside your sub DivisionApprovals() before you send the emails.  This is going to change up your code quite a bit but this function is ready to go and you can post it at the bottom after your sub and you can simply call it inside your sub by invoking its name.

Comment: gets tricky with the pivot if its not named, if you keep opening the wbook and its already there the creation of it causes a problem naturally (it already exists).  So 1) you delete it and recreate it each time or 2) check for its existence and if its there continue if not create and continue  I am sure the SO community can offer some solutions

Comment: classic view in the pivot options buts rows beside each other rather than below, it is compact.  Run a macro recorder and just create a small pivot of dummy data in a blank workbook, it will show the choices made and the resulting code.

Comment: @learningthisstuff - Wookies explained it in last comment. let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Okay, I got it to display correctly, thanks.  I do not think this option will work though.  The pivot itself I could see helping, but this report is generated multiple times per day and the data changes each time.  So, the source data table would change every time, with more or less rows.  I am also unsure as to how to actually USE this pivot data in the macro, meaning, how to point to each spot.  You are right, though, this pivot is an exact representation of what I am trying to get done!

Comment: i tried to run Scott's code here but it errors out right at the Set pt = .PivotTables(1).  Error says Method 'PivotTables' of object '_Worksheet' failed.  Wookie, is there a way to just adjust MY code to look at the pivot table and pull values directly via my loop?

Comment: @learningthisstuff - in regards to data changing multiple times/day with more / less rows, base the pivot table on a [dynamic named range](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) and just refresh in code to update it. So set it once and forget it. Regard error on `Set pt = .PivotTables(1)` that references the first pivot table in the pivot tables collection of `Sheet1`. Modify my code to set it directly to the pivot table name of the sheet you have. So modify `With Sheet1` to whatever sheet you have (Sheet1 uses code name). and `Set pt = .PivotTables("myTable")`

Comment: I add some code pieces about pivots below the original answer that I am using in another project.  You will have to clear your mind and understand what I am doing and then bend it to your project.

Comment: Maybe that will help you build pivots from scratch vba and manipulate them in the ways that you wish.  You then have to go through each row until you hit a new name . . . . that is code I did not include but I can try and relate some for you.

Comment: Also there is a way to do it the way you are doing it once you have the unique list go through each unique name and create the email for each unique, then compare to each cell in your column and add the departments, when the range is done send the email and move to the next unique name. Not very efficient but "brute force" and its done.

Comment: Ha, I like brute force!  How would I do that?  Just point at cell.value and then offset method?

Comment: Scott, thanks by the way.  I did change the sheet name and modified that line.  Named my table Table1 and set that as Set pt = .PivotTables(Table1) but got a different error, saying variable not defined.  I do not think I am skilled enough to make your code work, but thank you!

Comment: `.PivotTables("Table1")`. All string literals need quotes. You are skilled enough. You just don't have the experience to know it :)

Comment: answered the code as is, but you should still learn and play with pivots, they are more effective for what you are after.  The answer is a brute force column blaster with your code (slightly modified), but the largest change is SORTING the names first, the code was written with this expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different technic to solve the same problem with Excel. First of all I have a Function to open a new ADODB-Recordset:

```
Function RST_Excel(strExceldatei As String, strArbeitsblatt As String, strWHERE As String, Optional strBereich As String, _
                   Optional strDatenfelder As String = "*") As ADODB.Recordset

Dim i As Integer
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnection As String
Dim strSQL As String


On Error GoTo sprFehler

strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & strExceldatei

If global_con Is Nothing Then

   Set global_con = New ADODB.Connection

   With global_con
        .Open strConnection
        End With

   End If

strSQL = "SELECT " & strDatenfelder & " FROM [" & strArbeitsblatt & "$" & strBereich & "] WHERE " & strWHERE

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With rst
     .Source = strSQL
     .CursorLocation = adUseClient
     .ActiveConnection = global_con
     .Open
     Set RST_Excel = rst
     End With

sprEnde:

Set rst = Nothing

Exit Function


sprFehler:
Set rst = Nothing

Set RST_Excel = Nothing

End Function
```

Then I open the ADODB-Recordset from another Routine:

```
Dim strWHERE As String
Dim strFields As String
Dim rst_Recipients As ADODB.Recordset

strWHERE = "Surname IS NOT NULL AND Emailadress IS NOT NULL"
strFields = "Surname, Name, Emailadress, SMIME"

Set rst_Empfänger = RST_Excel(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "Email", strWHERE, "A1:M1000", strFields)
```

As the query is passed as an SQL-Statement you could also pass an Statement to get unique results.

The advance for me is that I could easily move through the Recordset:

```
With rst
     .movefirst

     do until .eof
        debug.print .fields("surename").value
        .movenext
        loop

end with
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but it is way over my head!  I do not understand how to set this up, I am still just learning VBA and do not know anything about SQL.  I tried to call the function, but don't I need a sub that would run to call it?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to put the second code to a sub.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to do what you want to do.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it just created one email for every person.  I need it to create one email with all the attachments, looping through.